# Wrong sum aggregation result elastic 5

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query which returns wrong result **(all the sum buckets =175!)**, and I don't have a clue why.. assistance will be appreciated.
I'm 99% sure that it didn't happen with Elastic 1.7 (we have just upgraded)

```
GET org_aggregations...*/.../_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              "AVqE7pJdCQ_f2txT8s4x"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "create_date": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "create_date",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "greater_than_val_time": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "groovy",
              "inline": "_source.histogram_time_distribution.histogram_timegreater_than_val"
            },
            "size": 20
          },
          "aggs": {
            "recurrences": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "histogram_time_distribution.histogram_timedoc_count22"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**the only doc retrieved from the bool filter is:**

```
  {
    "_index": "..",
    "_type": "...",
    "_id": "AVqE7pJdCQ_f2txT8s4x",
    "_source": {
      "doc_count11": 175,
      "page_views": 88,
      "histogram_dns_time_distribution": [
        {
          "histogram_dns_timegreater_than_val": 0,
          "histogram_dns_timedoc_count22": 175,
          "avg": 0
        }
      ],
      "histogram_time_distribution": [
        {
          "histogram_timegreater_than_val": 0,
          "histogram_timedoc_count22": 161,
          "avg": 193.17391304347825
        },
        {
          "histogram_timegreater_than_val": 1000,
          "histogram_timedoc_count22": 7,
          "avg": 1323.142857142857
        },
        {
          "histogram_timegreater_than_val": 2000,
          "histogram_timedoc_count22": 4,
          "avg": 2270
        },
        {
          "histogram_timegreater_than_val": 3000,
          "histogram_timedoc_count22": 0,
          "avg": null
        },
       ...
      ],
      "resource_domain": "stats.g.doubleclick.net",
      "resource_path": "/r/collect",
      "create_date": "2017-02-25T00:00:00"
    }
  }
```

**the strange result is: (all the sum buckets =175!)**

```
"aggregations": {
"create_date": {
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key_as_string": "2017-02-25T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key": 1487980800000,
      "doc_count": 1,
      "greater_than_val_time": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 6,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "0",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "recurrences": {
              "value": 175
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "1000",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "recurrences": {
              "value": 175
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "10000",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "recurrences": {
              "value": 175
            }
          },

          ....
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using now?

Comment: I am using version 5.2